# Where can I ask logo design related questions?

Tags: support, asking-questions

I want to create a logo but I want to get some ideas on mixing few things.

1. Is there any site where I can discuss that? It's not any software related but guidance on logo design
2. Is there any SO site for questions related to PETs?
3. Also on general 3Ds max , should I go on game development or Super User

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to [StackExchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/sites) to review all sites offered. YOU's mentioned the [Graphic Design beta](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/); I see nothing for pets other than the [Parenting beta](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/) (I kid! I kid!)

New sites are proposed and discussed on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) prior to being launched. Review what's available there, and maybe propose a note site for your interests. I see there's a [Pets proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5489/pets), still early in the definition phase.

As far as 3DS Max, there are 19 questions tagged with variants of "3DS" on superuser, and 10 on Game Development. The latter don't seem to have been well-received. I'd start with superuser.

Comment: u mean anyone can propose site . i would like to have site for **Adults** questions . Is that possible :) . Is there any possibility of having smiley images in comments

Comment: +1 for parenting beta :P

Comment: @Mirror51: It's possible, but unlikely to be accepted. I'll bet it's been tried before. As far as a smiley, I see one in your comment. Do you want an animated one or something?

Comment: nearest one would be http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3303/everything-you-always-wanted-to-know-about-sex-but-were-afraid-to-ask regarding Adults @Mirror

Comment: @Michael , i mean smileys u have in yahoo messenger and in forums @YOU thanks for that , i wonder when they will be live . i am desperate to ask questions

Comment: @Mirror51: you can ask, here on Meta, for "true" smileys in posts and comments. You might hit a record for the lowest-voted request in the history of Meta. I guarantee that people won't want that. :)

Comment: @Michael i saw that . i take my words back ;)

Answer (score 2):

Probably [Graphc Designs](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) & Upcoming [3D Graphics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5022/3d-graphics-techniques-and-software) site.

For Pets, there is a proposals - http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5489/pets, but I am not sure that would go to beta anytime soon.