# Why don't you have a site for pets?

Tags: support, site-proposal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I ask logo design related questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89572/where-can-i-ask-logo-design-related-questions)

I'd like to see a site for pets.

A site for pet owners, where you can ask questions and people would answer. It is hard to find any good answers out there about training and taking care of pets. Most of the information is like copy-paste from other sites, no real experience.

Comment: There is one these days: http://pets.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 10):

You could propose the creation of one. But there is already a proposal for the creation of such a site, see [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5489/pets).

Have also a look at this Area 51 [FAQ](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq).